# Buffer Overflow error while using Simple.Data.Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, orm, simple.data

I am using Simple.Data.Oracle to insert data in a table. I am trying to insert a very large value in one of the columns and it is giving me the following error

ORA-22835:Buffer er for lille til konvertering af CLOB til CHAR eller BLOB til RAW (faktisk: 19471, maksimum: 4000)

I am a long way ahead in the project and can't afford to dump Simple.Data.Oracle and look for other alternates at the moment...

Comment: Thanks Ben but I want to insert the entire value taking a sub string will not be useful in my case. Is their some way of declaring a CLOB type parameter in Simple.Data.Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're converting a CLOB to a string of some description. There's a maximum of 4,000 characters in a string in SQL so you need to take a sub-string of the CLOB if you want to place it into a character.

The simplest way to do this is to use [`DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_lob.htm#ARPLS66748).

It doesn't appear as though `simple.data.oracle` supports CLOBs natively; if you look at [the code for the `DBTypeConverter` class](https://github.com/flq/Simple.Data.Oracle/blob/master/Simple.Data.Oracle/DbTypeConverter.cs) the dictionary maps a CLOB to `DBType.String`:

```
{"CLOB", DbType.String},
```

This is despite [the documentation linked in the comments](http://docs.oracle.com/html/B14164_01/featOraCommand.htm#i1007424) indicating that it should be mapped to `DBType.Object`. Though the mappings have changed very slightly in the [11.2 documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e23174/featOraCommand.htm#ODPNT255) a CLOB is still an object.

I don't know the reasons for deciding that a CLOB is a string but as I see it you have a few options:

1. Raise a bug report on GitHub and be prepared to be told it's not a bug.
2. Pull a version and change it yourself - be warned that as a CLOB is assumed to be a string there may be a lot of changes to make.
3. Use `DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR` and "chunk" the CLOB into as many strings as are required using the offset parameter.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I ended up using ODP.Net for this specific case as I really could not afford to invest more time into finding a permanent solution.